# Power BI - Group By (power query ) Vs measures ! Which one is more powerful

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Should we use the group by function in Power Query and create a new table, or is it better to create as many measures as we need ? (one measure for each column) ?

Which one is more powerful?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your purpose. If you have a granular fact table that you want to aggregate first before creating the data model, you can do that through Power Query before feeding the model. Even then, I would recommend doing it on the server-side if you are bringing a SQL table; so that you can perform a native SQL group by rather than having to do it through Power Query syntax solely. Power Query has some performance lagging and each `nth` step in PQ is evaluated from `1st` step internally and it requires a full refresh of the table.

However, if you only want to perform group by to be utilized in an analysis, it is always a good idea to use DAX measures and refrain from using PQ. Also, you can't resort to PQ for different analysis scenarios. `DAX` is built for those scenarios and it is extremely powerful. `DAX` measures are the most powerful concept of Power BI. Also, they get evaluated in filter context/slicers; i.e. respond to the selection of values in slicers and / or whatever is present in the Axis (business case)

There are tons of supports for DAX measure optimization, such as SQLBI, Stack, Power BI community. If optimized correctly, DAX measures enhance report performance tremendously without creating any lagging in the report at all.

Few resources to look into
[1](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/comparing-dax-calculated-columns-with-power-query-computed-columns/)
[2](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/)
[3](https://radacad.com/measure-vs-calculated-column-the-mysterious-question-not)

Comment: "Power Query has some performance lagging and each nth step in PQ is evaluated from 1st step internally" -- if you're in the query editor, then yes. -- If you're not, then it's one result. Note, this [does not mean you cache query results when query `B` and `C` are  set to `reference` query `A`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-referenced-queries). In that instance, `A` is evaluated 3 times. (Dataflows are a different story)

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a new table in power query, it means results are pre calculated and there will be some performance gain if we consider report usage. But, it will increase your Data Model size. Where as Measure will calculate things on the fly. This will keep your model size same but add some slowness in the presentation part. As a whole, there is no specific answer for your question as per my knowledge as it depends on so many other things like-

- Your data size
- How many measure you wants to create
- How complex your logic inside measure's
- How often you need reload your data
- and so on...